# What is the opposite of the vernal point?

Tags: terminology, ecliptic, right-ascension

The equator and the ecliptic cross at two nodes. One of those nodes is the vernal point. What is the other one called?

Comment: Linguistically it would be "autumnal point" but I don't see that term has much usage.

Comment: Another option is to use the terms [first point of Aries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Point_of_Aries) & first point of Libra, which has the benefit of not being northern hemisphere-centric. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring that [sounds familliar](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41309/whats-the-method-behind-this-tdrs-triplet-inclination-madness#comment134528_41317) ;-)

Comment: Using first point of Aries and first point of Libra means you need to change the name on a regular basis, to account for precession, though.

Comment: No, because the first point of Aries is defined to be the March equinox point, so it tracks the precession of the equinoxes. Hence the 1st point of Aries is currently in the constellation of Pisces. Astronomers (mostly) stopped using the zodiac signs for ecliptic longitude notation in the mid-1800s, but of course astrologers still use them. ;) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zodiac#Twelve_signs

Comment: The correct term is of course the *antivernal point* :-)

Comment: @uhoh Does the smiley mean your comment is ironic, or is antivernal the actual term?

Comment: @usernumber it's meant as humor. I don't think it's a correct term.