# What are the correct symbols for vernal and autumnal equinox?

Tags: history, symbols, nomenclature

What are the correct symbols for vernal and autumnal equinox?

I have seen people use both ♈︎ (\Aries) and $\gamma$ (\gamma) to denote vernal equinox. However, I have never seen the symbol for autumnal equinox. Should it be either ♎︎ (\Libra) or $\Omega$ (\Omega)?

Are ♈︎ and ♎︎ the conventional symbols to use?

Are $\gamma$ and $\Omega$ sometimes used just because they resemble the above symbols?

An alternative name for vernal equinox is First Point of Aries. Is there a similar name (First Point of Libra) for autumnal equinox?

Comment: FWIW, here's a recent related (but unanswered) question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35400/16685

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on [astronomical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_symbols#Symbols_for_zodiac_constellations_and_signs) says:

> The zodiac symbols are also sometimes used to represent points on the ecliptic, particularly the solstices and equinoxes.
>   Each symbol is taken to represent the "first point" of each sign.
>   Thus, ♈ the symbol for Aries, represents the March equinox; ♋, for Cancer, the June solstice; ♎, for Libra, the September equinox; and ♑, for Capricorn, the December solstice.

The article cites Roy and Clarke, *Astronomy: Principles and Practice*.
[This question](/q/32235) copies an example usage of ♈ and ♎ from that book.
[Stellarium](https://stellarium.org/) uses the same symbols if you set View: Markings to show the equinoxes and solstices.

$\gamma$ is a poor substitute but clear enough if ♈ is unavailable.
Since $\Omega$ stands for an orbit's [longitude of ascending node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_of_the_ascending_node) (angle ♈-☉-☊), it would be a confusing substitute for ♎.

"First point of Libra" is archaic but correct.
These names and symbols represent tropical zodiac signs, not IAU constellations.
♎ is fixed at ecliptic longitude 180° regardless of constellation boundaries.
Its location in Virgo this century doesn't change its name or symbol.